# How To Solve This Laravel Function

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have created a Registration form. I want to show a message like "you can't book this" when someone tries to insert a date , show time(st) and seat number(item) which are already in the database. And if that data not in the database , he can insert it. Then I created a function called seatsinsert in SeatsController.php. But , when I click submit button nothing happens. Even I can't find an error message.

When I check , console of the browser , it shows this.

> http://localhost/FinalProject/public/seatsinsert 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)
>
> XHR failed loading: POST
>   "http://localhost/FinalProject/public/seatsinsert"

And in Network tab -> Response shows me a huge message , even I can't read it.

Laravel Log.

> [2018-03-13 09:51:35] production.ERROR: No application encryption key
>   has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0):
>   No application encryption key has been specified. at
>   D:\wamp64\www\FinalProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:42)
>   [stacktrace]

How can I Fix this ??

Here is Seats.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" method="POST" action="{{ route('seatsinsert') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">    

    {{ csrf_field() }}    

    <h4> <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span> </h4>

    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Select Date :</label>
    <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" id="example-date-input">
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Select Time :</label>
    <select name="st" class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
      <option>10.30 am</option>
    </select>
    </div>  

      <h2 style="font-size:1.2em;font-family: Times New Roman;"> Choose seats by clicking below seats :</h2>

      <div id="holder"> 
    <ul id="place">
        </ul>    
      </div>

      <div style="width:600px;text-align:center;overflow:auto"> <br>       
         </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnShowNew" value="Continue"> <br><br>

      @if(session()->has('Msg'))
      <h4 class="alert alert-success"> {{ session()->get('OnlyImg') }} </h4>
      @endif 

    <br />   

    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#btnShowNew').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var items = [];
                $.each($('#place li.' + settings.selectingSeatCss + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                    items.push($(this).attr('title'));
                });

                   //console.log(items);
                   // $(location).attr('href', 'Seats');

                   $.ajax({ 
                    type: "post", 
                    url: "{{ route('seatsinsert') }}", 
                    data: { 
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", 
                    items: JSON.stringify(items), 
                    date: $('input[name=date]').val(), 
                    st: $('select[name=st]').val()}, 
                    success: function(data){ 
                    $("form").trigger("reset"); 
                    $('#success_message').fadeIn().html("Text"); 
                    } 
                    });

                }); //btnShowNew

         }); //Final
```

Here is my SeatsController.php

```
public function seatsinsert(Request $request)
    {

        $date = $request->input('date');
        $st = $request->input('st');
        $item = $request->input('items'); 
        $items = str_replace(['[', ']', '"'], '', $item); 

        // Validation

        $query = DB::table('seats')
        ->where('date', '=', $date)
        ->where('st', '=', $st)
        ->where('item', '=', $items)
        ->count();

        dd($query);

        if($query > 0 ) { 
    $request->session()->flash('Msg', 'No Seat');
        return redirect('Seats');
    }
        else{

        $user = new Seats(); 
        $user->date = $date; 
        $user->st = $st; 
        $user->item = $items; 

        $user->save();
        $request->session()->flash('Msg', 'OK Seat Inserted');
        return redirect('Seats');
        }

    }
```

Here is my Router.

```
Route::post('seatsinsert',[
'uses'=> 'SeatsController@seatsinsert',
'as' => 'seatsinsert'
]);
```

Comment: Check your log file for recent error which is located at `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Also add error log to question to help you better

Comment: Too much code for me to read, but you are getting `500`, that means server is not correctly set up or you have error in code; inspect `..../logs/laravel.log` for more information. Good luck.

Comment: That "huge message" is the page returned by laravel, and I guess it contains the exception stack error message. You'd better check it, because it's probably in its first lines of the stack message where you'll find the description and offending line error.

Comment: By the way, you know you can't see anything because you are using ajax to send the post (and receive the response), right?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham - I added Log to the question.

Comment: @Kyslik - I have added logs to the question. How can I Fix it ??

Comment: @Amarnasan - I have added logs to the question. Is there a way that I I can Fix this ??

Comment: You have't set the application key in environment file. Use `php artisan key:generate` to create one and check for any errors

Comment: `No application encryption key has been specified.` Launch the artisan command i told you in answer....

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham - Still , when I click submit button nothing happens. Even I can't find an error message.

Comment: Use `php artisan key:generate` to generate the key. After that you are using ajax to send the request, so you can't use `session flash` and `redirects` there. You need to return errors using `response->json(['error' =>'message'])`

Comment: Also you are running project directly from public folder, Use `php artisan:serve` else your ajax routes will not work.

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham - In Controller or view ??

Comment: In the controller

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham - I think my Laravel log didn't update. So , thats why I can't see exact error. Because Now 3.50pm and still it shows me 9.51am. error.

Comment: It is showing 9:51 because you have't updated your correct timezone yet. That's not a problem

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham - How can I use " response->json(['error' =>'message']) " this in Controller. I tried , but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

a simple `php artisan key:generate` may solve the problem

Comment: Still , when I click submit button nothing happens. Even I can't find an error message.

Comment: You don't have to click any submit button, just to run that in the command line

Comment: open your command line interface, go to your project rot directory and run this artisan line...

Comment: Yes , I did it.. I mean after I run this command. Still , I can't submit my form.

Comment: Yes , still the same.. May be Laravel log didn't update. So , thats why I can't see exact error. Because Now 3.50pm and still it shows me 9.51am. error.

Comment: try a `composer du` (i think you've got to make it each time you generate a key but not sure of this)

Comment: I think Laravel log didn't show me the error. Because I made a mistake and checked the logs. It showed that error. After I change back and try again with this Registration form and still I have the previous error. No new errors..

Answer (score 0):

Well, now is obvious with the error message:

You need to generate the key.

```
$> php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: I think my Laravel log didn't update. So , thats why I can't see exact error. Because Now 3.50pm and still it shows me 9.51am. error.

Answer (score 0):

Open the cmd and just run the `php artisan key:generate` command